# How to use appropriate AL runtime version?

Tags: .net, windows, sdk, msbuild

I'm trying to link several files into one library, and I use next command

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\al.exe /out:obj\Debug\my.dll /template:obj\Debug\template.dll /embed:obj\Debug\class.cs

I'm expecting to retrieve an assembly of 4.6.2 .NET Framework, but actually I'm getting 4.0 version.

Current Windwos SDK version is 7, and I use Windows 8.1. I've already tried to install SDK 10, but I've not found a way to change current SDK version.